# mysql libs conflict with with mysql client

Tags: mysql, centos5, yum, configuration

I am trying to get redmine up and running and its not been going well.  Currently I am trying to install the required package mysql-devel and getting the error:

Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0 from install of mysql-libs-5.5.23-5.el5.art.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysqlclient18-5.5.17-4.el5.art.x86_64

Both Google and this site have suggested uninstalling & reinstalling mysql.  But this is a live server and I dont want to do that.  Is there another way around this problem?

Thanks,

k

Answer (score 2):

I'll wager a guess: the only reason the devel package is needed is because it creates a more general .so name, presumably named /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so pointing to the pertinent version. Simply creating this symlink by hand should prolly be sufficient.

You should be able use:

```
strace -f -e stat64,open -p <redminepid>
```

during the failing operation to see what libs it is looking for.

I'm shooting from the hip, OP but having waited 15 minutes for an answer from someone who actually know what (s)he is talking about, this is better than nothing (I hope :).

For future systems, I recommend the MySQL community builds for CentOS 5 boxen. Install server, client, shared and devel from the beginning, and you should be able to dodge this sort of issue.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  i cant use strace yet bc redmine isnt installed correctly yet.  the conflict error is the result of 'yum install mydevel' for the prereq's according to their wiki.  i'm working on the symlink angle now

Comment: which direction should things be pointing? I would think it would 2 libraries in the symlink. But the error makes it sound like mysqlclient18-5.5.17-4.el5.art.x86_64 should be a smlink to mysql-libs-5.5.23-5.el5.art.x86_64 ??  I've been working on this all night and cant think logically anymore.